# FastAPI определение имени субдомена и передача в функцию

Tags: python, fastapi

Делаю онлайн меню для кафе. у каждого кафе свой субдомен cafe1.menu.com, cafe2.menu.com, cafe2.menu.com.

Как в роуте определить имя субдомена и передать его в функцию?

Answer (score 0):

Нужно получать данные запроса [напрямую](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/using-request-directly/), из них можно вытащить URL и имя хоста:

```
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
def read_root(request: Request):
    return request.url.hostname


if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=5000)
```

При переходе на `http://0.0.0.0:5000` вернет `"0.0.0.0"`. Если у вас URL фактически будет `cafe1.menu.com/...`, то и имя хоста будет `"cafe1.menu.com"`.

Соответственно, вам нужно будет из имени хоста вытащить первую часть (хоть через `split` или `partition`, хоть через регулярное выражение), и передать ее в функцию.